# Javascript does not free memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran a simple experiment in Ubuntu: made 1500mb dummy file, then did `fs.readSync` of that file. Then made `f = undefined` and reassigned it to 15. I was expecting that the memory will free after I make `f = undefined`. I did the same experiment in Browser (Chrome) using `<input type="file">` FileReader and had the same results: memory was freed only after tab was closed or reloaded. Is it supposed to be this way?

The chart bellow is from Ubuntu system monitor showing memory usage.

[image]

Comment: In the Memory tab if you click the bin icon in the top left (Collect garbage) does it go down then? If so then you don't have a memory leak and Chrome has decided that it doesn't need to free up memory yet (i.e. it's an implementation detail of Chrome rather than a problem with your code)

Comment: Garbage collector does not run just after developer reassigns a variable. Garbage collection implementation depends on the engine, there is no exact logic behind to be predicted by developer.

Comment: I'm assuming this memory hasn't leaked. Contents of the file might've been freed, but size of the heap didn't change, because the engine might assume something else might use just as much memory.

Comment: Memory is freed if claimed by another process, or explicetely freed by yours.